# Using LINQ Aggregate() function to create object of existing type

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I can use the following syntax to aggregate my collection:

```
Dim Result = Aggregate X In MyCollection _
             Into Prop1 = Sum(X.Val1), Prop2 = Sum(X.Val2)
```

but the type of `Result` is anonymous. What if I want `Result` to be of an existing type? I tried using `New` as we do in `Select` clause, but that doesn't seem to work.

Note: Further investigation reveals that the *method syntax* does accept a `TResult` argument where I can specify a transformation function. So I'm basically looking for the query syntax equivalent of that.

Comment: Can you chain a Select _after_ the Aggregate?

Comment: @metacubed: hmm... yes, probably, but plz check my edit. The method syntax does have it, so should the query syntax, no?

Comment: @metacubed: Actually no. The result of the above aggregation would be a single row, so there's no way to use `Select` on that.

Comment: Not sure what you need in the end result - how about `Dim query = Aggregate X In MyCollection Into props = Sum(X.Val1 + X.Val2)` Shows as an `Integer`. Or what is the type your after?

Comment: @OneFineDay: If you supply multiple properties (just like I did: Prop1 and Prop2), it will create an anonymous object with those properties in it. What I want is to ask it to return object of an existing class instead of an anonymous one. `Select` clause has the same behavior, but in addition to returning anonymous objects, it supports using `New` keyword with a class name and assigning properties to it through `With` keyword; all that right inside the query. I'm looking for that exact thing in the `aggregate` query.

Comment: I realize that, `Result.Prop1` has it's sum and `Result.Prop2` has it's sum - so what the problem? Create your other class object and populate with these results.

Comment: @OneFineDay: I can do that manually of course. I was just wondering about the equivalent query syntax for something that is already supported by the method syntax; i.e. specifying the result type *within the query*.